# How to find the normal distribution in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, standard-deviation

I'm trying to convert a formula from an Excel spreadsheet into an online calculator, the formula specifically is:

```
=(NORM.S.DIST(2.5467437 + -1.9344945 *B7^( -0.5),1))^2
```

The problem I'm encountering is that [NORM.S.DIST](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/norm-s-dist-function-HP010335691.aspx) doesn't appear to exist in any Javascript library that I've found. In researching the problem I did find this solution, but it's [a C# based one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408214/Excel-Function-NORMSDIST-z) and I don't know how to convert that into Javascript. How do I approach this problem in Javascript?

Comment: > *I don't know how to convert that into Javascript*  That code contains only arithmetic. Are you writing a JavaScript app? This would be a great exercise for you to learn js, by converting that code line by line.

Comment: @CrescentFresh I certainly am, and that's exactly what I'm doing - but  I can't find the JS equivalent to this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:**

This varies from the actual value by less than `0.005`:

```
function cummulativeNormalDist(x) {
    if(x < 2.2) {
        return .1 * x * (4.4 - x);
    } else if(x < 2.6) {
        return .49;
    } else {
        return .50;
    }
}
```

Source: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalDistributionFunction.html

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

For any normal distribution defined by the mean and SD, let myval be the value for which you want to find the centile.

If you want just to return the output of NORM.S.DIST in excel, just skip the centile function.

```
var myval = 14;
var mean = 15.5;
var SD = 4.8333;

var answer = centile(mean, SD, myval);
console.log(answer);

function centile(mean, SD, val)
{
    z = (val-mean)/SD;
    ans = NORMSDIST(z);
    return ans;
}

function erf(x)
{
    //A&S formula 7.1.26
  
  var ans = 0;
    var a1 = 0.254829592;
    var a2 = -0.284496736;
    var a3 = 1.421413741;
    var a4 = -1.453152027;
    var a5 = 1.061405429;
    var p = 0.3275911;
    x = Math.abs(x);
    var t = 1 / (1 + p * x);
    //Horner's method, takes O(n) operations for nth order polynomial
    ans = 1 - ((((((a5 * t + a4) * t) + a3) * t + a2) * t) + a1) * t * Math.exp(-1 * x * x);
    return ans; 
}

function NORMSDIST(z)
{
    var ans = 0;
    var sign = 1;
    if (z < 0) sign = -1;
    ans = 0.5 * (1.0 + sign * erf(Math.abs(z)/Math.sqrt(2)));
    return ans;
}
```

working pen:
https://codepen.io/RichClarke/pen/oNdpoRM?editors=0011